# How to remove unnecessary blank line on code formatting in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, goland

Is it possible to remove empty/blank lines using code formatting in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Just to notice, the accepted answer doesn't work on HTML. It works only for java , python, etc.

Comment: you can also look for regex $\n\n and replace it with \n (original idea from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206344569/comments/206917645)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to configure the number of blank lines in the settings menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ATL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>): `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java(or Scala or whatever your language is) -> Blank Lines`

[image: Blank lines configuration]

Comment: Where can I set it for //region //endregion?

Comment: Weird: when I set "Before method body" to 1, don't add an empty line there, then format the code, the empty line is automatically added. But the other way around: I set it to 0, do add an empty line there, then format the code, the empty line is not deleted.

Comment: @Rule It's because it's "Minimum". Not "Maximum" or "Exact" numer of lines.

Comment: @Danon you're right, didn't catch that. Would be nice if they provided this option though

Comment: I've submitted a feedback to JetBrains just now, asking whether they'd implement it. I'll post a comment when I get a response :>

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work _after_ the opening brace `{`. So I cannot remove the empty lines after opening a class or a method.

For lines before the closing brace `}`, works like a charm.

I also cannot delete a line after a class ending `}` brace.

Answer (score 41):

You can find and replace with regex option also `^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+`. It searches all empty lines in file. You need to just replace it with empty

Answer (score 40):

- File >> Setting >> Editor >> Code style java  >>Blank lines tab
- You should change to 0 in code label(as picture), It would remove all unnecessary blank line when press format shortcut: **ctrl + alt + L**

[image]

Answer (score 20):

I use regular expressions to remove extra blank lines from the code. Here are the instructions.

- Open **Find and Replace** dialog. Use shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
- In the search box type `^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r)){2,}`. This will search for two ore more blank lines.
- In a replace box type `\n`. This will replace with one blank line.

[image]

- Open **Reformat Code** dialog and click **Run**. Use shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

This works on all JetBrains IDEs. Use the screenshot as referece.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it helps someone using newer versions of Intellij, in Intellij IDEA 2016.2.4 it is `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java(or Scala or whatever your language is) -> Blank Lines`

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to remove blank lines at the end of the file, this became a feature as of [August 2020](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119281#focus=Comments-27-4326233.0-0).

The proper place to configure this action is under Settings|Editor|General|On Save. Check "Remove trailing blank lines"

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered this problem and here is the solution I found out.

Minify your code to one line and then style it like you normally would.

```
ctrl + shift + j //shortcut to oneline
ctrl + alt + l   //shortcut to styling
```