# Code formatting shortcuts in Android Studio for Operation Systems

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting

I have started developing with [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). In Eclipse I was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but in Android Studio it does not work. It will be different.

How can I jump to any method in a `.java` file? I was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in Eclipse.

Is it available? What is the shortcut for code formatting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Its just intelliJ with some addons.  So whenever you have a "how do I" question on it, search for the answer for intellij

Comment: For a complete list of shortcuts visit http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#KeyCommands

Comment: u could also record a macro like "CMD + SHIFT + L" and then "CMD + S" and set the CMD+S Shortcut to this macro. u can record a macro in Edit->Macros->Start Macro Recording. And you can change the shortcuts in AndroidStudio->Preferences->KeyMap, where you'll find your saved macro in "Macros" and the Save-Action (where you have to remove the CMD+S shortcut) in Main menu->File.

Hope this is an additional Help! 
I think it's faster to format on save because you should be saving your code often anyway.

Comment: See also "Intellij Idea Keyboard Shortcuts" http://wiki.c2.com/?IntellijIdeaKeyboardShortcuts

Answer (score 1899, accepted):

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

macOS: <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Reference: [Key Commands](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#KeyCommands) and here are all of the commands for [Windows/ Linux users](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) and for [Mac users](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf).

---

As Rohit faced a problem in Ubuntu with the format code shortcut, this is due to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> key being used to lock the screen in Ubuntu.

I found that Ubuntu handles this keyboard shortcut first. So you should bind the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcut to something else so that it doesn't conflict with Ubuntu.

### Steps

1. Go to *System Tools* → *System Settings* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* tab → *System* → *Lock Screen*.
2. Select the row *New Accelerator...*, then press any special key with the Alpha key (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>). You should've successfully changed the keyboard shortcut.
3. Check if the keyboard shortcut now works in Android Studio.

### Alternative method

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (to show a dialog)

---

You can also use Eclipse shortcuts.

- Windows and Linux: Go to menu *File* → *Settings* → *Keymap*
- macOS: Go to menu *Preferences* → *Keymap* and choose Eclipse from the drop-down menu.

#### Using MenuBar

- Select code which you want to reformat
- Click on **Code** in the menu bar and select *Reformat Code* as shown in the image below:

  [image]

In Android studio 3.5, there is problem with rearranging the xml code, it also rearrange the views as well, so need to use these settings first.

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML-> Set From -> Predefined Style > Android.

## Update for Android Studio 4+

Since Android Studio 4+, you might face issue shortcuts on mac. [Shortcuts not working after updating to Android studio 4, in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305912/shortcuts-not-working-after-updating-to-android-studio-4-in-mac) have an answer for that.

Comment: Thanks. can you please tell me how to jump to any method in android studio.in eclipse `ctrl+o`

Comment: it does not format the comments. if i have given more space before a comment line it will stay there until i manually cut all those space. please do suggest a walk around.

Comment: @SagarNayak For that you need to set lines into editor's settings. Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118204/how-to-remove-unnecessary-blank-line-on-code-formatting-in-intellij or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354301/how-do-i-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-android-studio

Comment: Also works in PyCharm (at least on Mac), so I assume this could be a helpful answer for users of all JetBrains products (not only Android Studio)

Comment: @jmartin Correct. Actually Android Studio is customized JetBrains, so almost all shortcuts are same.

Comment: Ohh. They don't understand how it is important to format the code during the writing. Why? Why on NetBeans I dont bother about what shortcut it should be? Or recall that stuff. Just rightclick and format!

Comment: EDIT 3 : Using MenuBar... only helped me for rearranging XML. I tried many times alt+cmd+L in mac Android studio but no luck.. for java file it was working fine.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + L not working when i tried with korlin.

Answer (score 113):

You can also use Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts: just go to menu *Preferences* → *keymap* and choose *Eclipse* from the dropdown menu.

---

The actual path is: menu *File* → *Settings* → *Keymap* (under IDE settings)

Answer (score 74):

Check *[Keyboard Commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)* given in the Android Studio Tips & Trick documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 33):

Just select the code and

- on Windows do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- on Linux do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- on Mac do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

[This solution from junaidp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044472/correct-indentation-in-intellij)

Comment: P.S. It's probably a good idea to state what the "Windows key" is especially on a Mac running Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 16):

For formatting code in Android Studio on Linux you could instead use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. You could use this and avoid having to change the system shortcut. (<kbd>Super</kbd> key is the Windows icon key besides the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key).

Comment: This solved my problem. Not sure why this wasn't mentioned in android's Keyboard Commands document.

Answer (score 12):

For code formatting in Android Studio:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Windows/Linux)

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Mac)

The user can also use Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts: just go on menu *Setting* → *Preferences* → *Keymap* and choose Eclipse (or any one you like) from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 11):

You will have to apply all Eclipse shortcuts with Android Studio before using all those shortcuts.

Procedure:

Steps:

```
Setting -> KeyMap -> Select Eclipse -> Apply -> OK
```

Now you can use all Eclipse shortcuts in Android Studio...

Have some snapshots here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

For auto formatting your Java/XML files in Android Studio, use following commands:

As you are looking for a single point to go with your work as Eclipse did, there is no such built-in functionality in Android Studio, but it gives you the ability to do it through a macro. Follow these steps:

In Android Studio, open any of your source code files.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> This is used to find/optimize unused import.

If a dialog open select "Don't show it again" and hit Run.

Go to *Edit* > *Macros* > *Start Macro Recording*.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. This formats your code. (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for Ubuntu).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This saves your file;)

Go to *Edit* > *Macros* > *Stop Macro Recording*.

Save this created macro with a name, for instance: “Auto Formatting".

Boom, you have now successfully created your macro. Now just add/assign a shortcut to it:

Open *Preferences*.

Search in the left bar for *Keymap*.

In the right hand pane, click in the search bar and type the name of your saved macro ("Auto Formatting".)

Double click on your item. There might be two, it doesn’t matter which one you click on.

Click *Add Keyboard Shortcut*.

Set your keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Finally, confirm overriding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to be your new macro.

Answer (score 9):

Check this. Also you can change it as per your preference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to @user2340612 answer to switch keymaps to Eclipse, the path for Android Studio 1.0.1 is:

Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Keymap* (under the *Editor* option) → *Keymaps* = *Eclipse*

Answer (score 7):

In addition to auto-formatting that the other answers describe, another trick is to highlight the text that you want to indent and then press

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to increase the indent or
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to decrease the indent.

[image]

Check out the [Keyboard Shortcut docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts) for more.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> might conflict with Lock Screen shortcut in Ubuntu. In such case you can change the keyboard shortcut for Reformatting Code as follows:

**File-> Settings-> IDE Settings-> Keymap**

Search for Reformat Code and change the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

Really, I went to this thread because of my Ubuntu locks screen after this shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. So if you are have the same problem just go to the **Settings - Keyboard - Shortcuts - System** and change the default shortcut for the "Lock screen".

Answer (score 5):

For those who are wondering about the alignment issue inside bracket, JetBrains has this as in their issue tracking.

Here is the answer:

> [How do I align/format code in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223188/how-do-i-align-format-code-in-android-studio/28225339#28225339)

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut that worked for me is

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

You can optimize imports to remove the ones you don't use, and auto import the new classes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think is clear that for **code formatting** in Android Studio the combination keys are:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Win/ Linux)
>
> <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Mac)

However, we forgot to answer about the Jumping into the method.
Well to go into any declaration/implementation there three ways:

1. Goto Declaration

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CLICK</kbd> (Win/ Linux)
>
> <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>CLICK</kbd> (Mac)

2. Goto Implementation

These commands show a list of all the classes/interfaces that are implementing the selected class/interface. On variables, it has the same effect as Goto Declaration.

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Win/ Linux)
>
> <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Mac)

3. Goto Type Declaration

These shortcuts will go into the declaration of the “AnyClass” class.

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Win/ Linux)
>
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Mac)

Additionally, there is a shortcut for Goto the Super Class. This will open the parent of the current symbol. Pretty much the opposite of Goto Implementation. For overridden methods, it will open its parent implementation.

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (Win/ Linux)
>
> <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (Mac)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Dart plugin, go to Android Studio, menu *File* -> *Settings*.
And search for "reformat code with", click "Reformat code with dartfmt" under the main menu:

[image]

Click "Add keyboard Shortcut".
Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and the shortcut should work (If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> make the computer sleep/suspend, change the shortcut in your system settings to something else. Otherwise, both shortcuts will collide).

Answer (score 4):

Some times even I type Ctrl+Alt+L is not working in XML, so found this way to make it work.

> Go to Settings --> Editor --> Code Style --> Select Default --> Ok.

For your reference see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This result came up for me when I had this problem and the above didn't help. For me it turned out I had "Mouse Without Borders" running and this was consuming my <CTRL>+<ALT>+L keypress. Closing Mouse Without Borders fixed it for me. Just posting here incase someone else with the same issue gets fed this same result ;)

Comment: Thanks for posting it! @Slartibartfast

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

- On Windows do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- On Linux do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for dialog to open and then reformat.
- On Mac do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Note: Here many answers for Linux is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> 
      which is wrong. In Linux, doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> locks the system.

Comment: The lock happens because in Linux DE like KDE the shortcut is set for locking the desktop. For KDE, Change it from `KDE Menu -> System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gesture -> Global Keyboard Shortcut`, then in KDE Component spinner select The KDE Session Manager. Clear **lock session** shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for Windows.
For a complete list of keyboard shortcuts please take a look at the user manual: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 2):

There are some shortcut keys for rearrange or reformat code in Android studio.

Linux: Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L

mac OS: Option + Command + L

Windows: Ctrl + Alt + L

Answer (score 1):

I have had an experience using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Windows that this shortcut did not work at all because it was reserved by another software, running at the background; which I realized later.

I decided to mention this issue as I thought it may be helpful . . .

Answer (score -1):

The best key where you can find all commands in Eclipse is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

By pressing this you can get all the commands in Eclipse.

One important is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to import and un-import useless imports.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following shortcut for code formatting: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>