# How do I align/format code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting, code-readability

Is there a way/shortcut/built-in feature that can align code for operands, like '=' signs?

For example, there is a XAlign for Xcode (https://github.com/qfish/XAlign), allowing the user to select code that needs to be aligned and use a shortcut to align it automatically.

There is a *Fields Group* feature in Android Studio which can "Align in columns", but it does not work for code that is already written.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code formatting shortcut in Android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio)

Comment: I don't think there's a built in formatter for aligning by `=` in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 56):

#### Indent code in Android Studio:

---

**Windows**

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

---

**Mac:**

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: That changes the screen orientation on my laptop. VERY annoying.

Comment: @CoolMind, Thanks for the suggestion, but I no longer have that laptop. I am on a MacBook now.

Comment: Works good on a file level but I wonder if there is a way to do modification on entire project or even better to do it automatically when I open a project?  Upvoted

Comment: @pixel Use the re-format code shortcut in the project/android file view highlighting/selecting the folder thereby navigation to Code > Reformat

Comment: Working on macbook Catalina. Thanks

Comment: It's ctrl+alt+shift+L on my WIndows machine. I wish I knew where the menu item was ... if there is one.

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse which comes with Android Studio Bundle, the shortcut key is as follows to initiate *Auto Formatter*:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

If you want to change this combination, go to menu *Preferences* → *Keymap* and set to custom.

Comment: I am on Mac. [Command + Option/Alt + L] does not work. i have the Field group "Align in column" turned on. but selecting code and reformatting does not seem to work.

Comment: Yes. Keymap are default. using the shortcut bring up the Reformat Code but it does not reformat the code. the = sign does not align for variable declarations for the selected code.

Comment: i think it's CTRL + SHIFT + F

Answer (score 6):

The alignment for variable declarations works for only those that are outside of functions. The alignment feature in menu *Preference* → *Code Style* → *Wrapping and Braces* → *Fields Groups* → *"Align in Columns"* does not work for those inside the brackets/braces.

Here is an issue ticket on the JetBrains website: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56947#

This feature is available, but not in the stable release yet. It is available from build: 140.1761

At the time of writing this answer my current build is "135.1653844, built on December 18, 2014" on Stable Release.

Answer (score 4):

Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

macOS:

<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows and Linux in Android Studio:**

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**For Mac:**

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Linux:  Ctrl-alt-L (suggested by other responses) is captured by the window manager and locks the screen.  So you need to change it: file->settings->keymap->main menu->code->Reformat Code.  I use a double tab since I don't want the tab to shift a selection right.

This formats the code as you've specified in your preferences.  To handle your specific request (aligning equals statements) go to: (file->settings->editor->code style->(choose language)->Wrapping and braces->Group declarations->align variables in columns

These styles are language specific so this particular option might not exist in the language you chose, or may be named differently.