# How to align XML code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, code-formatting

is there any feature in Android Studio to align all XML attributes by '=' sign. I am unable to find any setting that would allow this.

[image: un-aligned]
[image: aligned]

Just another code format fanatic who likes code readability.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: I've never actually seen anyone do this style of XML formatting for Android layouts. Not saying it's wrong or anything. Just never considered it.

Comment: I have not seen it either but coding in objective-c allowed me to simply align everything which made readability so much more efficient for me. which was made easier by XAlign (https://github.com/qfish/XAlign) plug-in for Xcode. since i couldn't find a way to do this though i ask. when i manually did the alignment it helped a lot with readability for the xml code and made it easier to look thru the file quickly. just a personal pref. :) @MattLogan

Answer (score 12):

below code will align everything but not after = sign. for better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio)

Win/Linux:

> Ctrl + Alt + L

Mac:

> Option + Command + L

Comment: Not Works to me!

Comment: Tey Ctrl + Alt + L  on Ubuntu & locks my computer!

Comment: Worked on my Mac like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Settings - Editor - XML

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but am just nitpicking. there isn't really a solution, the alignment/wrap options allow for tags or attributes and even add spaces between equal sign but not necessarily for alignment of equal sign within the given attributes in the xml files. :D