# Android Studio, navigating through methods

Tags: android

In android studio, pressing the **Ctrl + click** on a method navigates to the method implementation. Now, I am not getting how do I return to my previous position(where I had clicked) using some shortcut (like in eclipse **Ctrl + left arrow**).

Between, I am using Linux machine.

Comment: Read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio/16580200#16580200 and map keys as eclipse

Comment: By setting the key maps to Eclipse(in dropdown), now I am able to navigate back. Thanks much, Pankaj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the keystroke is **Ctrl + Alt + Left**.

It can be found under the Settings Window->Keymap as **Main menu->Navigate->Back**

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Linux machine.

Comment: So what does the keymap say?

Comment: Of course, since you had to go into the Keymap settings, you could have just looked up what the keystroke was at that point

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio uses a left arrow as a Back Button (see illustration):

If it isn't showing: (using: Studio 2.1.2 Windows)

- Ensure toolbar is visible: Click Help> Find Action> in the dialog, type "Show Main Toolbar" click "On" in the dialog.
- If the "Back" arrow is not visible, enabled it: "Right Click" a blank area of the Main toolbar, select Customize Menus and Toolbars, navigate the popup to "Main Toolbar" and click "Restore All Defaults".

[image]