# Android Studio on Mac, how to fix "Unexpected token" on whitespace?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I'm new to Android Studio, and have ran into an issue where I paste in a code from a web tutorial into a project, fix imports, and still have every single line having some leading whitespace which the Android Studio recognizes as "Unexpected Token". After manually selecting the offending whitespace and deleting it, the errors disappear.

I tried Option + command + L [shortcut for code formatting, but that did not fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio)

How can I fix "Unexpected Token" error for code pasted into a .java file in Android Studio?

[image]

Comment: find/replace should do it

Comment: You also may want to try 'Paste Simple' - ctrl alt shift v. That will paste it as simple text.

Comment: Did you copy and paste code from the internet?

Comment: how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't comment due to user level, but this is definitely a case of invisible characters from whatever web encoding you copied from.  It's pretty common to copy whitespace from a website and it's not actually whitespace.  It's a space-keeping invisible character used for website formatting, or even just an artifact from diferent character encoding that didn't copy over properly due to different character formats.

**In short, just find/replace (⌘+R)**.  Any time you copy something from a website, you run the chance of this error.  Just be glad your IDE lets you know about it.

[image]