# How to set max line length in Android Studio code editor?

Tags: android-studio

How can I set a maximum length for Android Studio's code editor, or may be set a word wrap?

In my Android Studio, no matter how long a statement I type on a single line, it never automatically goes to the next line, but rather a horizontal scroll bar appears.

When I autoformat using the `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio#answer-16580200)), nothing happens.

My SO or Google search found a lot of material on this for Eclipse, but not for Android Studio.

Answer (score 76):

If you need **not a soft wrap**,
but actually, brake one long line onto several lines you need:

**Go to Preferences(mac) or Settings(windows) -> Editor -> Code style -> Java/Kotlin -> Wrapping and braces (tab) -> Check "Ensure that right margin is not exceeded"**

Now try to reformat your code:
press
OPTION (ALT) + CMD + L  on your Mac
(or CTRL + ALT + L on PC)

**Edit 13.02.19**

As noted in comments this option seems not available in settings for Kotlin.
However, there is a workaround to manually add it.
Here is what it takes to make it work:

1. Export the settings scheme.
   [image]
2. Open saved xml file.
3. Find  `<codeStyleSettings language="kotlin">` tag (or create)
4. Add the WRAP_LONG_LINES setting manually:

   ```
   <codeStyleSettings language="kotlin">
      ...
      <option name="WRAP_LONG_LINES" value="true" />
   </codeStyleSettings>
   ```
5. Save edits and and import back the scheme.
6. Here you go!

Comment: I think it is "Settings", not "Preferences". Sits in the "File" menu.

Comment: It depends on whether you are on Mac or PC

Comment: this option is not available for kotlin in andriod studio 3.2

Comment: Created an issue about this problem in Kotlin for JetBrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229595

Comment: @KonstantinZyubin is your feature request the same as supporting `WRAP_LONG_LINES`

Answer (score 74):

MacOS:

1. Click on Android Studio ( left top corner )
2. Click **Preferences**
3. Type **Code Style** in search
4. Click on Code Style
5. There is a filed right to the **'Hard wrap at'** - you can enter needed about of symbols you need

   [image]

Comment: for dart you have to set the dart file line-length limit, **Preferences->Editor->Code Style->Dart->Line Length**

Comment: any reason why at Dart it's only 80?

Answer (score 37):

In File | Settings, select "Editor", then "Code Style". There is an option "Wrap when typing reaches right margin".

Edit: Just tried it, and it doesn't seem to work. Anyway, maybe the option "Use soft wrap" in the  "General" group is more what you want.

Answer (score 27):

With version 4.1.2 and with **Dart** language you need to go to "File/Settings/Editor/Code Style/Dart" and modify the "**Line length**" to the preferred number.
[image]

Answer (score 19):

@Solace, actually @Fahim Faysal's answer is quite close to what you need, but since you want to solve the problem *`no matter how long a statement I type on a single line, it never automatically goes to the next line`*, 2 more steps you need to follow:
**[Step 9]** type the max length you prefer at `***"Hard wrap at"*** ()
**[Step 10]** change ***"Wrap on typing"*** from **Default: No** or **No** to **Yes**

[image]

Answer (score 14):

**In Android Studio:** 
File->Setting->
Editor->code Style->java->Wrapping and braces(tab:right side)->keep when reformatting->Line break(make unchecked)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

For dart
settings => code style => Dart => Line length

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can change the max column width from:
File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Right Margin (columns)

Comment: When I change the right margin, after I restart Android Studio the margin value is reseted to 100. To avoid it, I have to go to java / wrapping and braces and then change right margin to my value (for example 150) AND change Wrap on typing to NO, then APPLY...

Comment: THANK YOU. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio 3.5:

Mac - 
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > CodeStyle > `HardWrap at: ____`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The existing answers already answer the question in straight forward way. As a different approach you could set the style guide to `kotlin style guide` code style. Then if you do `alt + ctrl + l` as you did, you'll see auto wrap as you expected.

1. Just open the settings, search for `kotlin` and look for `kotlin` under `code style`.
2. On the top right hand side of the settings window you'll see `Set from...`, click on it.
3. Then on `predifined style > kotlin style guide`

[image: Android studio settings]

If you'd like to follow the kotlin formatting style this could reduce more effort. For more information: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide

Answer (score 4):

My Environment：

- Ubuntu 18.04
- AndroidStudio 3.3.2

My operate：

- File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style

  1. Scheme -> select Project
  2. Hard wrap at '120'
  3. Apply

Answer (score 2):

To move the grey vertical line, that tells Android Studio where to wrap your code, go to

*Settings- Editor- Code Style- Java or Kotlin- Wrapping and Braces- Hard wrap at*

and enter the number of characters, where the line should be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In settings/code style/kotlin/wrapping and braces replace the "do not wrap" values with "wrap if long"

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **Hard wrap at** param

[image: Hard wrap at]