# How can I disable Line Breaking when string is too long

Tags: java, android-studio

So I have this base64 formatted image and i keep it in a string, but seems the editor keeps breaking the line when the string is too long. It's annoying for me because the base64 almost filled most lines in the editor.

I have unchecked Soft Wrap in Settings > Editor > General, unchecked Ensure right margins is not exceeded, changing maximum soft wrap lines but none of them works. I have looked every single question and none of the answers worked for me.

So this is what I'm having right now

```java
String base64string = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALUAA
AC1CAYAAAAZU76pAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP..."
```

I'm expecting to have this

```java
String base64string = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALUAAAC1CAYAAAAZU76pAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP..."
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set max line length in Android Studio code editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851617/how-to-set-max-line-length-in-android-studio-code-editor)

Comment: @jhamon It's what the editor shows to me, here the picture: https://ibb.co/1f2xCWj

Comment: @jhamon I have looked that question and none of the answers worked.

Comment: the part about soft wrap in the first answer didn't work?

Comment: @jhamon Nope, literally checking and unchecking many times didn't worked.