# How to increase the width of the code line in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, code-formatting

I am using Android studio to develop a flutter app, when I click reformat code with dart format it breaks in unpleasing format.
[image]

Even though there is lot of space it breaks the line, how can i increase the line width?

Comment: Check if its a plugin causing the issue or check this out if it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851617/how-to-set-max-line-length-in-android-studio-code-editor

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I changed Settings->Editor -> Code style -> Dart -> Wrapping and braces (tab) ->  ``changed Hard wrap`` at to '150'

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I solved this issue by  changing **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart -> Line length**  to **150**

Comment: To me it was.....
Settings->Editor -> Code style -> Dart -> Line length

Comment: For me this moves the vertical guide, but Dart auto formatting still breaks the line after 80 chars. Any solution?

Answer (score 10):

FOR MAC OS:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart -> Line length: int

Answer (score 7):

Go to settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart, you can change line length to what ever value you want, but based on Effective dart style, it's better to avoid lines longer than 80 characters. see this docs https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to change the settings, maybe with an Android Studio plugin, but as described in the Dart docs you should avoid lines with more than 80 characters of code. Try to structure your code a bit then you have more overview instead of squeezing everything in one method, widget or whatever together

[Link to Dart docs](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/lines_longer_than_80_chars.html)

Comment: IMHO, this rule has negative effect in common. Actually it is rudimental rule from the past.  
As Linus Torvalds said:  

`People with restrictive hardware shouldn't make it more inconvenient for people who have better resources. Yes, we'll accommodate things to within reasonable limits. But no, 80-column terminals in 2020 isn't "reasonable" any more as far as I'm concerned. People commonly used 132-column terminals even back in the '80s, for chrissake, don't try to make 80 columns some immovable standard.`

Answer (score 2):

For VS Code:

> File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Dart&Flutter:  Dart: Line Length

Comment: This does not answer the question which specifically concerns Android Studio. Nevertheless, your answer might be useful for VS Code users.