# Android Studio - how to remove "Avoid lines longer than 80 characters" inspection alert

Tags: android-studio, dart, code-inspection

I am using Android Studio, is there any way to disable this annoyed inspection.

[image]

I tried to disable all inspection, invalidate cache and restart but still

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890488/how-to-increase-the-width-of-the-code-line-in-android-studio

Comment: @ecle thanks for the link but this is a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that there is lint configuration in the code, so just disable and the alert will gone.

In
`analysis_options.yaml` file, disable the 80 chars rule:

```
linter:
  rules:
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: false
```