# Reformat Whole Project Files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting, android-studio-2.2

I need to update my code style. Reformatting the whole project files one by one takes too much effort with the [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580200/4376058) I know.

> <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

## **My Question?**

Is there any other way to do it for the whole project?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Use the re-format code shortcut (default: `⌘ + Opt + L` (Mac) / `Ctrl + Alt + L` (PC)) in the Project Files View/Explorer on the desired root folder(s) and then check `Include subdirectories`.

[image: Project File View]

[image: Reformat Code Options]

Comment: You saved me from millions of conflicts.

Comment: @ErenUtku I second you. :)

Comment: In android studio tree view - right click on the desired root folder - select "Reformat Code".  Pop up will appear select desired action.

Comment: It skipped some files for me, do u know the logic how can it happened?

Comment: There are some checkboxes like only changes uncommitted to VCS, Scope, File mask. Maybe one of those are checked?

Comment: suspicious indentation goodbye!

Answer (score 16):

**This is how it works in Android Studio 3.5**

**Right click in your project or lib -> Reformat Code**

See the image below:

[image]

**Select what you want** (clean up code will reformat your code)
[image]

Wait until the progress finish.

**that's it!**

**Good coding!**