# How to indent XML code in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

How can I reformat (add indentations) to my XML code in android studio 2.3.3 for windows? I have tried ctrl+alt+L but it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio

Comment: thanks i  got it it is alt+ctrl+shift+L

Comment: Since the actual command has `L` (capital L) in it, you need to use `shift` key too.

Comment: thank  you very  much

Comment: Asif if you have got the answer I consider you to close the question or mark an answer correct.

Comment: If you have received an adequate answer to your question, please mark an accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code formatting shortcut in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

You need to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key because the actual command is <kbd>L</kbd> (Capital L).

Answer (score 3):

Go to  System Tools -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts Tab -> System -> Lock Screen

Ubuntu: Ctrl + Alt + L

MAC: Option + Command + L