# Shortcuts not working after updating to Android studio 4, in Mac?

Tags: android, shortcut, android-studio-4.0, android-shortcut, keymaps

After updating to Android Studio 4 from AS 3.5, as a Mac user I found out none of the default shortcuts work properly, i.e `cmd+shift+F` does not open `search everywhere dialog` anymore?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To fix : 
in Android studio, from top menu tap on  `Android studio` then `Preferences...`  and type `keymap` then in the drop-down on the right screen select `Mac` and `apply`.

all sorted now,  all the shortcuts are aligned with the Mac keyboard.
[image]

Comment: Huge thanks for this! I have this problem every time I update AS. Such a simple fix.

Comment: For a few seconds I was terrified because I couldn't find the `macOS` option. Then I realized I had to scroll...

Comment: Jesus. I need to do this everytime I update android studio

Answer (score 8):

Try `control+shift+F`.
I don't know why Android Studio makes this change, as that's such acommon used shortcut.

Comment: they have updated their short keys to the site: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

For those using VSCode keymaps, make sure you're using VSCode(macOS) keymaps in `preferences > keymaps`.