# Shortcuts to Find File and Find in Path no longer work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

I updated my Android Studio to 4.2 and the shortcuts to Find a File, and Find In Path no longer work. For mac these used to be `Cmd + Shift + F`, and `Cmd + Shift + O` respectively.

I tried looking at the guide on the developers' website and these two are still listed as the correct shortcuts, yet when I press the nothing happens anymore.

Anyone else facing the same issue, or have found an alternative shortcut for the aforementioned actions?

Comment: For some reason Android studio 4.2 resets the default keymap. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305912/shortcuts-not-working-after-updating-to-android-studio-4-in-mac

Comment: Thanks @IvanWooll , I hadn't seen that post.