# Ctrl +c and Ctrl +v is not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, copy

I am able to copy text from other programs and paste it to Android Studio. I am able to right click and copy selected text. I am able to cut text and paste it using shortcut. But while using shortcut Ctrl + C to copy text I am often unable to copy. This is very annoying problem. Does anyone here knows how to solve it?

Comment: The issue is real and happens for me time to time, today it started again after AS upgrade. Not sure why stackoverflow users put minuses on this without explanation

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio (like all JetBrains IDEs) is very configurable.

Check its Keyboard Shortcuts to see if Ctrl+C is a shortcut to the text copy command in text panes:

1. Preferences > Keymap
2. Click the second magnifying glass icon ("Find actions by shortcut").
3. Type Ctrl+C (or Cmd+C). --> Is it mapped to Main Menu > Edit > Copy?
4. Type `copy` into the magnifying glass icon filter text field. --> Look through the different commands and their shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed IdeaVim in your Android Studio. Please remove this, restart and try again. Hope it will work.

You can check IdeaVim plugin is installed or not in Setting->Plugins

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same happens for me after Android Studio Upgrade.
I found out that a new keymap `Visual Studio Copy` appeared and was selected by default

[image]

So the solution which worked for me was to change the keymap from `Visual Studio Copy` to `Visual Studio`

The issue was already raised in [Shortcuts not working after updating to Android studio 4, in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305912/shortcuts-not-working-after-updating-to-android-studio-4-in-mac)

> in Android studio, from top menu tap on Android studio then Preferences... and type keymap then in the drop-down on the right screen select XXX and apply.