# some devices give error mistake (invalid double value )

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying with some calculating codes ... but in some devices the app just broke down ...
and the message was invalid double value

the related code as the following

```
final double totalValue; double fValue1 = value1* amount1 /totalAmout;

final double value1  ;
                  final double value2  ;
                  final double value3  ;
                  final double value4  ;
                  final double value5  ;
                  final double value6  ;
                  final double value7  ;
                  final double value8  ;
                  final double value9  ;
                  final double value10 ;
                  final double totalValue;
                  if (firstSp.getSelectedItemPosition()  >0 & firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() <= elementsArraysArray.length  )  { value1 
= Double.parseDouble(elementsArraysArray[firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() -1][i -1]);       if (amount1 ==0 || amount1ET.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){amountB = false;}      }else if (firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() == elementsArraysArray.length + 1) {value1  = addedOneArrayList.get(newALindex).getValueOfElement(); if (amount1
==0|| amount1ET.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){amountB = false;}} else if (firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() == elementsArraysArray.length + 2) {value1   = addedTwoArrayList.get(newALindex).getValueOfElement(); if (amount1
==0|| amount1ET.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){amountB = false;}}  else if (firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() == elementsArraysArray.length + 3) {value1  = addedThreeArrayList.get(newALindex).getValueOfElement(); if (amount1
==0|| amount1ET.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){amountB = false;}}  else if (firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() == elementsArraysArray.length + 4) {value1  = addedFourArrayList.get(newALindex).getValueOfElement(); if (amount1
==0|| amount1ET.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){amountB = false;}} else {value1  = 0;}
                 
                    double fValue2 = value2* amount2 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue3 = value3* amount3 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue4 = value4* amount4 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue5 = value5* amount5 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue6 = value6* amount6 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue7 = value7* amount7 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue8 = value8* amount8 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue9 = value9* amount9 /totalAmout;
                    double fValue10=value10*amount10 /totalAmout;

                    totalValue = fValue1 +fValue2 +fValue3  +fValue4   +fValue5  +fValue6  +fValue7  +fValue8  +fValue9  +fValue10;

final DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
finalArrayList.add(new SelectedItem(contentElmntsArray[(i / 2) - 1], Double.parseDouble(form.format(totalValue))));
```

could you guys please advice

**UPDATE:**
the mistake was here `Double.parseDouble(elementsArraysArray[firstSp  .getSelectedItemPosition() -1][i -1]);`
in some old devices where the language of divice is Arabic , **the device translate the number (inside the String)** so it will not be able to extracted as a type of number variable

Comment: the formatting on your code is very difficult to read, you should really consider [formatting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcuts-in-android-studio-for-operation-systems)

Comment: I track the problem ... its happen for some values that extract from String and the number is Integer and doesn't have a decimal point >> but still don't know how to fix it